# Why godaddy mvc application won't deploy to plesk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was having a problem deploying an already-functioning mvc application to the new godaddy plesk hosting.

I was getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

However, I was able to solve it eventhough I never found the answer on stack exchange or tech support.

So, I am posting it here for future souls.

The solution was that plesk, the new godaddy hosting requires a specified index.
So, I had to specify the global.asax as the index where typically one may have index.html or soforth.

Comment: I think you should edit this to fit the question/answer format. i.e. post the question, then post your solution in an answer.

Comment: If this is meant as a self-answered question, please post the answer as an actual answer. Also, _"specify the global.asax as the [default document]"_ doesn't really sound as a solution to antything, let alone an assembly manifest mismatch, so you might want to emphasize _why_ that would solve this in this specific GoDaddy/Plesk combination and explain _how_ one would do so.

Comment: I have a new account so couldn't answer my own question for a min. of 8 hours.

Comment: You do have a point about the assembly manifest mismatch, though.

Comment: I did have to solve the assembly references problem first which was the easy part.  It was the obscure fact that you must specify the global.asax as the default that appears to be what a lot of people are missing.  It is a minor detail that is not obvious since their old hosting did not require it.

Answer (score 0):

I also run MVC4 on my personal site (which is on Plesk Hosting) and I personally didn't run into this issue (and I don't have a default.aspx since MVC uses routes).

If you login to Plesk, go to the Websites & Domains tab... From there, you should be able to pick "Web Server Settings" and then you'll notice an option "Default documents".  It *should* by default be set to "Enter custom value" which then shows a listbox with about 12 or 13 options.  If just picking "Enter custom value" doesn't work, you can (like it sounds you did) add your global.asax there too and you should be in business :)