# ASP.NET MVC Deployed to Plesk 12.5 throws Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wif, plesk

I've deployed an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to Windows Server 2012 running Plesk 12.5 hosted by GoDaddy.  I located this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420315/why-godaddy-mvc-application-wont-deploy-to-plesk) and added Global.asax as specified.  I also installed Windows Identity Framework on the server but the error still persists.  The detailed error can be viewed [here](http://www.familyandfriend.net/Account/Register).

What further actions must be taken to ensure that the account login and registration features work as they do on my development machine?

Comment: please go through this article http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/30886/registration-pages-not-working.aspx, this should solve your problem. remove anti forgery and try to run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for receiving this error is because probably you don’t have the Windows Identify Foundation Pack installed.  To resolve this problem, dowbload and install the Windows Identity Foundation Pack.
https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=17331